# Show Scrollbars outside overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a few columns horizontal scrollable inside. 
The table can have hundreds of rows and so it is placed into a scrollable div container.

```
|--------------------|   ||
| table              |   ||
|--------------------|   ||
|  |       |  |  |   |   ||
|  |       |  |  |   |   ||
|--------------------|   ||
    =======              ||
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/d8ac33ph/4/)**

Functionality is ok so far. BUT the horizontal scrollbar should be always visible, regardless of the vertical scroll position. How can this be handled?

```css
body { 
  padding: 20px;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

th,td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
th { font-weight: bold; }
    

.table1, .table3 {
    float: left;   
}        
.table2 {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;  
}

#wrapper {
  width: auto; 
  height: 120px; 
  overflow-y: scroll
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
    <table class="table1">
      <tr>
        <thead>
          <th colspan="2">Termin</th>
        </thead>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Di</td>
        <td>12.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Di</td>
        <td>19.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mi</td>
        <td>13.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mi</td>
        <td>20.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fr</td>
        <td>15.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fr</td>
        <td>22.12.2017</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    

    <div class="table2">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <thead>
           <th class="duration">0</th>
           <th class="duration">1</th>
           <th class="duration">2</th>
           <th class="duration">3</th>
           <th class="duration">4</th>
           <th class="duration">5</th>
           <th class="duration">6</th>
           <th class="duration">7</th>
           <th class="duration">8</th>
           <th class="duration">9</th>
           <th class="duration">10</th>
           <th class="duration">11</th>
           <th class="duration">12</th>
           <th class="duration">13</th>
           <th class="duration">14</th>
           <th class="duration">15</th>
        </thead>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>       
      </tr> 
      <tr>
       <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>       
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>        
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td class="duration">12</td>
       <td class="duration">14</td>
       <td class="duration">21</td>
       <td class="duration">11</td>
       <td class="duration">15</td>
       <td class="duration">19</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>
       <td class="duration">20</td>
       <td class="duration">102</td>
       <td class="duration">56</td>
       <td class="duration">89</td>
       <td class="duration">45</td>        
      </tr> 
    </table>    
    </div>
    
    
    <table class="table3">
      <tr>
        <thead>
          <th>Zimmertyp</th>
          <th>Verpflegung</th>
          <th>Prei p.P.</th>
        </thead>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DZ</td>     
        <td>HP</td>
        <td>79,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Junior Suite</td>     
        <td>VP</td>
        <td>279,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DZ</td>     
        <td>ÜF</td>
        <td>54,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suite</td>     
        <td>AI</td>
        <td>319,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DZ</td>     
        <td>HP</td>
        <td>79,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DZ</td>     
        <td>HP</td>
        <td>79,- &euro;</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 

</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible without javascript, but I'd like someone to prove me wrong.

Comment: Javascript would be ok, even jQuery or a Plugin. But I don't know a solution anyhow...

Comment: There are various solutions depending on various factors. For example, do you care about responsiveness? Judging from the example I guess not. Would the fixed columns be the same number each time? Would the fixed columns always consume the same width? The solution can vary from very simple to very complex..

Comment: Responsive: currently not a MUST. So: no.
Fixed columns: yes, always the same number and it would be possible to make them fixed width, as the text does not change. 
Just the scrollable block can contain different amount of cols each time.